# What does 'Trying to invoke method: (FileName).(FunctionName) couldn't be called' mean in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game in unity where it is just a simple farming game as it is my first project. The invoke function has no parameters, so that cannot be the problem. here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlantAndHarvest : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Variables here
    public float reach, germinationTime;
    public GameObject mainCamera, turnip;
    private GameObject item;
    public Text txt;
    RaycastHit hit;
    RaycastHit onFarmLand;
    public LayerMask layerMask, farmLand;

    // Voids here
    void Plant()
    {
        if (Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, 0.48f, Vector3.down, out onFarmLand, 1.5f, farmLand))
        {
            txt.text = "Click Left Ctrl to plant the turnip";
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            {
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z);
                void SpawnTurnip()
                {
                    Instantiate(turnip, new Vector3(pos.x, 0, pos.z), Quaternion.identity);
                }
                Invoke("SpawnTurnip", germinationTime);
```

You can see, this is where the error is.

```
            }
        }
    }
    void Harvest()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, reach, layerMask))
        {
            txt.text = "Click Left Ctrl To Grab The Object";
            if (Input.GetAxis("Fire1") == 1)
            {
                Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            txt.text = "";
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Plant();
        Harvest();
    }
}
```

Any Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Probably because its nested in plant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is that because `SpawnTurnip` is defined as a nested function, `MonoBehavior.Invoke` can't find it. `Invoke` isn't magic; it just uses reflection to search the current class for the appropriate method name. Because the method is actually exposed on the class - you couldn't do `PlantAndHarvest pah = new PlantAndHarvest(); pah.SpawnTurnip();` either - `Invoke` can't find it.

It would work fine to pass a reference to `SpawnTurnip` - it's in scope, so you could use it as a `delegate` - e.g. `Action st = SpawnTurnip;` and then pass `st` to something - but for some reason `Invoke` doesn't accept delegates (despite them being significantly faster than looking up a function by name). There might be a better way in Unity to do it.

You could also try to figure out the fully-qualified name of the `SpawnTurnip` function, possibly by saving it to a variable and then inspecting the fields. I'm not actually sure how to get a delegate's fully qualified name though, and it's not even guaranteed that `Invoke` would accept the fully-qualified name.

Comment: I cannot have `SpawnTurnip` as anything but a nested function, because I am using a variable defined in the function, which is `pos`, so do you have any ideas to keep `pos` defined without it already being defined as the players position?

Comment: Never mind, I just realised that I could have `pos` at the top with the other variables, but keeping it empty, then defining it in the function again. Thanks for the help!